# Converting grViz objects to DiagrammeR objects

Tags: r, data-visualization, figure, diagrammer

The function `DiagrammeR::grViz()` produces an object of class "grViz" and "htmlwidget". Unfortunately, most functions in `DiagrammeR` assume your graph is a `drg_graph` object and so you cannot simply pass the output of `grViz` to those functions.

Is there some way to convert the type of the object so as to use the functions from `DiagrammeR`, such as features to combine two graphs into one file or save the graph with specified dimensions and formatting?

```
library(DiagrammeR)

# Make graph
simple <- grViz("
digraph dot {

    # Graph statements
    graph [layout = dot, overlap = false]

    # Node statements
    node [shape = box, fontname = Helvetica]
    a
    b
    e

    # Edge statements
    a -> b;
    b -> e;
} 
")

# Check class
class(simple)
```